# Are there any clip-on fenders that provide as full coverage as bolt-on fenders?

Tags: commuter, fenders, rain

Are there any clip-on non-eyelet fenders that provide as full coverage as bolt-on fenders?

I live in Seattle and am buying a new carbon commuting rain bike. Many of the high end bikes do not offer fender eyelets. On the other hand, there are many new carbon gravel bikes that do provide fender eyelets. I am curious how important of a factor is it to consider a bike with eyelets. I understand clip-on fenders are available for any bike. But I read online that some clip-on fenders have a gap in their coverage or stop halfway down the wheel.

Are there any clip-on fenders that provide as full coverage as eyelet-installed fenders?

Comment: I have clip-on mudguards on one bike, and they are both shorter and much less stable than eyelet-mounted mudguards. Attaching them was more annoying, you need to use double sided tape and cable ties but the mount you end up with is still flimsy. The rubber junk that came with them was worse, but allows the mudguards to be completely removed fairly easily (refitting is the original PITA, obviously). I suspect the answer to your question is "no".

Comment: You should probably put your approx tyre width in the question - this will affect your options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. In fact the language most have settled on is "full coverage fender" instead of something like "bolt-on fender" for just this reason. Clip-on fenders and Raceblades/Speedez/etc offer a lot less coverage. In particular what they tend to not cover well are your face, your feet, and the bike.

There are various ways of making full fenders work on bikes that have the clearance for them but not the eyelets ([this type](http://www.axiomgear.com/products/fenders/accessories/axle-runner/) has become my favorite), and also there's the "reacharound" installation style, which can be okay but is somewhat of a kludge.

Honestly it now more than ever makes absolutely no sense at all to buy a bike intended for rain commuting that can't take full fenders. The options just aren't limited like they used to be.

Answer (score 1):

I had a set that had a sort of built-in plastic P-clip.  I got rid of them because they only fitted up to 25mm tyres (despite being described as for "commuter bikes" - I suspect a mistranslation) and I run 28/32mm.  They *weren't* the Crud Roadracer but were similar (a slightly cheaper copy perhaps). The Roadracer mk2 on ebay apparently only goes up to 23mm(!) but the [mk3](http://www.crudproducts.com/roadracer-mk3/) should go up to 35 mm.  I'm not going to sit through the fitting tutorial to check, but the gallery makes it look like they attach without eyelets

Comment: Crud Roadrace attach with rubber O rings and cable ties, they don't use anything like a p-clip

Comment: @Vorsprung fair enough.  The ones I had used plastic thumbscrews (but weren't Crud)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Crud Roadrace mk2 do offer as good coverage as a bolt on fender of the same size.  Plus they are lightweight and easy to fit

But there are two downsides

1. Crud roadrace are narrow so the comparison would be with a Salmon mudguard not a nice SKS P35
2. As Crud Roadrace are really tight clearance the road dirt rubs on them more than a normal mudguard and they tend to wear out much quicker.  Typically they last a few months, SKS last a year or two.

If you want a carbon bike do what I've done, get something like a Genesis Datum and fit SKS longboards

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the picture. That certainly looks like it fits the bill.